# Prove that $|A|=|\mathbb R |$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Consider a set $A=\{f \in \mathbb N^\mathbb N : (\forall n)\; f(n)\mid f(n+1)\}$, where 
$\mid$ stands for a relation of divisibility. Prove that $|A|=|\mathbb R |$

My attempts: 
It was easy to show that $|A|\leqslant|\mathbb R |$ since $f \in \mathbb N^\mathbb N$, and $\mathbb N^\mathbb N = \mathbb R$. 
Unfortunately I have no idea how to show that $|A|\geqslant|\mathbb R |$. Could you help me, please?

Comment: For any $n$, $f(n)\mid f(n+1)$ is that?

Comment: @PhyM is this statement even true? Every $f\in A$ has to be constant, doesn't it?

Comment: If he means: for any $n$, $f(n)|f(n+1)$, a non-constant example is $f(n)=2^n$

Answer (score 3):

Assume that $|[0,1]|=|\mathbb{R}|$.

For each $x\in[0,1]$, let $x_n$ be the $n^\text{th}$ term of the binary expansion of $x$.

Define $f_x(n)$ recursively by $f_x(1)=2$ and $f_x(n+1)=2^{1+x_n}*f_x(n)$.

For each $x\in[0,1]$ and $n\in\mathbb{N}$, $f_x(n)|f_x(n+1)$ and each function $f_x$ is different.

Therefore, $|A|\geq|\mathbb{R}|$.

I say $\geq$ because you could create many variations on this idea.

Comment: Or just $f_x(n) = 2^{n+x_n}$.

Comment: Yes, that works as well.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the map $F\colon A\longrightarrow\mathbb{N}^{\mathbb{N}}$ defined by $$F(f)(n)=\begin{cases}f(1)&\text{ if }n=1\\\frac{f(n)}{f(n-1)}&\text{ otherwise.}\end{cases}$$This map is a bijection. Therefore, $|A|=\bigl|\mathbb{N}^{\mathbb{N}}\bigr|=|\mathbb{R}|$.

Comment: I don't see how this map is a bijection. See my partial answer because I could take two maps, one starting with $f_x(1)=2$ and one with $f_x(1)=3$ but your $F$ would send them to the same place.

Comment: Could we address that by $F(f)(1)=f(1)$ and $F(f)(n)=\frac{f(n)}{f(n-1)}$ for $n > 1$..

Comment: @badjohn Right! I shall edit my answer. Thanks.